# Can't generate database scema during test

Tags: spring, h2, liquibase, jhipster

Im using jhipster to generate an app and everything but the tests is working wonderfully :).

I added entities and updated some manually. I used mvn liquibase:diff to generate changelogs and the application runs when I launch it in dev mode (running in tomcat on a postgres db).
When i try to run the tests i get a missing Table exception from one of the entity I added.

I think it has to do with liquibase not initialising the schema of the h2 embedded instance but I can't point out why.

Thanks in advance for your help,

Lucas